# Angle relations

Tags: geometry

Please can anyone help finding the solution.. I am working on this task in geometry and already found out some angles being $90^{\circ}$ and $17^{\circ}$ and $34^{\circ}$. I tried through the sum of the angles:

$$360^{\circ} = 197^{\circ} - \alpha + 90^{\circ} + 73^{\circ} + \alpha$$

but always didn't work out. can anyone please help me?

[image]

Comment: What's supposed to be special about the smaller circle? It looks like the lowest point can be shifted along the circle, thus (moving the small ciecle and) changing $\alpha$.

Comment: yes thats right, one could shift alpha.. but in this case just imagine, not to move it. i know that alpha has to be 51 degree. but i don´t the way of the solution and the explanation for this. do you have any idea? thank you!

Comment: Ah, I see. I think the right "hollow" point is the center of th ebig circle. That prevents my shifting ...

Comment: do you know the way of solving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct the line joining centre of bigger circle to the point of intersection of circumference of small circle and bigger circle. Use the fact that angle at centre is double of angle and circumference, base angles of isosceles triangle are equal and the angle subtended by same arc on circumference is equal to get answer 51(??). I will post a picture if possible.

[image]

Comment: yes i came until that part, with the double angle and the equal angles.. but then I lost because I had only angles sizes for the trianle on top. would be great if you could explain your solution. thank you!

Comment: okay thanks so much, I understood the design. but how do you know that the angleEDF  is the same like FGE? is there something congruent?

Comment: These both are the angles subtended by same arc EF on the circumference of circle.

Comment: Okay thank you so much for your help!! relly appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Denote the top point $P$, the bottom $Q$ and those on the horizontal diameter $A, B, C, D$ from left to right.

We are given that $\angle PDC=\angle PDA=17^\circ.$
Then 
$$\begin{align}\angle PQA&=\angle PDA=17^\circ&\text{(peripheral angle),}\\
\angle PCB&=\angle PCA=2\angle PDA=34^\circ&\text{(central angle),}\\
\angle BPC&=\angle PCB=34^\circ&\text{(isosceles triangle),}\\
\angle CPD&=\angle BPD-\angle BPC=\alpha-34^\circ&\text{(difference),}\\
\angle DCP&=180^\circ -\angle PDC-\angle CPD=197^\circ-\alpha&\text{(sum in triangle).}\end{align}$$
From the straight angle $\angle DCA$ we find
$$180^\circ = \angle DCP+\angle PCA=34^\circ +197^\circ-\alpha,$$
i.e.  $$\alpha=51^\circ.$$

Comment: thank you so much for your help. i really appreciate